# How to embed video using input tag

Tags: javascript, html, input, iframe, embed

I want to embed the YouTube video by iframe using input tag.

But it's not working where's the mistake -
**The entered URL is :- **
https://www.youtube.com/embed/G20AHZc_sfM

**Code in Body tag :-**

```
    <input id="url" type="url" placeholder="Video url">
    
    <button onclick="emb()">Embed video</button>
    
    <div id="link"></div>
```

**Code in script :-**

```
function emb(){
     var iframe,  urrl;
     var link= document.getElementById('url')
    iframe= document.querySelector("#link");
    
    urrl = `<center><iframe width="480" height="360" src="${link}"></iframe></center>`
    
    iframe.innerHTML = urrl;
            
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the value of an input just by selecting it. Use the `value` property in link:

```js
var link = document.getElementById('url').value;
```